# Recognizing new or already known document with VSTO

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, ms-office, vsto, powerpoint

I've never worked with VSTO and I've recently read all kinds of stuff about it. So I ask a theoretical question. I'm trying to make an addin which should (using buttons in it's own ribbon tab) upload the document to my website (it's like slideshare). The problem is that this file may be already uploaded and the user may be just trying to update it.

So I need a way to tell if this file has already been uploaded. I know the prediction can't be 100% accurate, that's why I'm going to ask the user with a dialog, but I need it to be fairly clever to alert the user if the file MAY BE is already uploaded.

This assumption can be client-side only, with a database of some sort (in the addin itself).
I thought of recording the file's name and based on this I can decide if the file is new or it's already uploaded.

Do you have any other ideas? Maybe there's more clever way to do this?

PS. Working on Office 2010 with the latest version of VSTO in VS 2010. My main .net language is VB but samples in C# are more than welcome (if you have ones).

Comment: Could the addin make an http call to a script on the server (as in give me the sha1 of your copy of this doc) ?

Comment: I can do anything I want with the server but I think you didn't understand my question. I want to be able to tell if the file is on the server, BUT the local (on the user's PC) may be changed. Imagine it like a synchronization tool. So a hash wouldn't work.

Comment: Think I must be missing the point; I was going to suggest that if your user wants to upload budget.doc you can query a server side script that returns a hash of its copy of that doc, or a not-found response, if the hashes don't match then the local users copy is different. Alternatively you could embed versioning metadata & comapre that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i'd probably do in that case is add a DOCUMENT VARIABLE or DOCUMENT PROPERTY with a value of a GUID.

Then when you push the file, the server could extract that property, get the guid and easily perform a lookup to see if the doc is already there.

At least, that'd be another way (other than say, user and filename) to id the document.

Comment: This is what I just thought, but I didn't know there was a way to embed data in the documents. I'm interested in doc/docx and ppt/pptx. Will it work for the older formats? Filenames are often changed so I'm trying to work around that.

Can you provide an example code that writes a var/property to the document itself? Or maybe some useful links?

Thanks so much :)

Comment: It looks like a royal pain but it's not that bad. See this MS article. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303296  It even has a big chunk of code that shows the necessary way to do this when running against various versions of word (they changed the typelibs between several versions for the CustomDocumentProperties property, so you can early bind to it consistently.

Comment: Thanks, I will check these out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Custom Properties but in PPT I'd use tags instead; the user can't see/meddle with them.

Assuming a reference to your presentation in oPres

```
With oPres
    .Tags.Add "Uploaded", "YES"
    .Tags.Add "LastUploadDate", "some string you've formatted to taste"
    .Tags.Add "AnythingElse", "You'd like to record"
End With
```

and

```
With oPres
    If .Tags("Uploaded") = "YES" Then
        ' nothing to do
    Else
        ' upload it
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What exactly is the difference between properties and tags? Why it's best to use one instead of the other? Thanks again :)

Comment: Functionally they're similar.  Both are collections (though Tags are always strings, custom properties can be other data types).  As far as I know, only PowerPoint has tags, so it might be simpler to write for multiple apps using properties.

On the other hand, PowerPoint allocates only a limited amouht of space to store properties, hyperlinks and possibly other stuff that's not documented.  Add too much data to properties and you could make a presntation's hyperlinks go corrupt. 

Again, the user can see (edit, delete) custom properties.  They can't see tags.

Comment: I need the solution to work on powerpoint AND word documents so it means I'll stick to the properties. I can shrink the property data to a simple int (an id) so size shouldn't be a problem here. Thanks again for trying to help :)

Comment: That sounds like a plan, especially given the tiny amount of data you need to store.